# How can I get a space in {{}}

Tags: angular

I want to get a space in html via block {{}}

```
I tried {{myVariable}}, then I got html with "&nbsp;"
may I know how can I get a html " " in block {{myVariable}}?
Thanks very much.
```

Example: `<div class="o-grid__cell o-grid__cell--width-75">{{task.word.phrase}}</div>`

transfer to `<div class="o-grid__cell o-grid__cell--width-75">someone&nbsp;who&nbsp;tells&nbsp;the&nbsp;actors&nbsp;in&nbsp;a&nbsp;film&nbsp;or&nbsp;play&nbsp;what&nbsp;to&nbsp;do</div>`

but i think it must to `<div class="o-grid__cell o-grid__cell--width-75">someone who tells the actors in a film or play what to do</div>`

in angular1 I search https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1505, but not understand how use in Angular2.

Comment: question is little confusing.. what are your expecting to happen?

Comment: i add example to post

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you want to show `my html {{" "}}` as `my html " "` . You can get html with `" "` inside interpolation by escapping `"` via `\\`

```
I tried {{"\\" \\""}}, then I got html " "
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7UroG6OXuDEBJ5H2mcLD?p=preview)

Even more better way would be `"`(double qoute) inside `'`(single qoute). No need of escaping.

`<summary>I tried {{'" "'}}, then I got html " "</summary>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngNonBindable, although it is currently [undocumented](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2236).

```
<div ngNonBindable>
{{ }}
</div>
```